# Make Pattern Rule not recognized

Tags: makefile, mingw

I'm currently writing a makefile that is able to compile different targets (Like Debug, Development, Release). The linking and compiling rules look like that:

```
$(DEVELOPMENT_OUT): $(subst rep,development,$(OBJS))
    g++ -o $(DEVELOPMENT_OUT) $(subst rep,development,$(OBJS))

obj/development/%.o: src/%.cpp
    g++ -c -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
```

Now, I get this output:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/development/Main.o', needed by 'bin/Development.exe'.  Stop.
```

But shouldn't the pattern rule apply for the Main.o?

I use `GNU Make 3.82.90` of MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information here to say why it doesn't work.  If you're sure you have a file `src/Main.cpp` then make should choose that rule.  Is the cpp file a source file, or a generated file?  If it's generated then maybe the real problem is lower down, where the generating happens.  You can try using `make -d` to see what make is doing and why it doesn't like this rule.